# R Shiny: How to change background color of a table

Tags: r, shiny

I found how to change the background color of the User Interface in Shiny. The withdraw I found is that it also colors the background of the tables i'm showing with `tableOutput`. Here I show a dummy example.

ui.R

> shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
>   headerPanel("Dummy"),
>   sidebarPanel(
>       tags$hr()    ),
>
> mainPanel(
>
> ```
> # This is what I use to change the background color
> list(tags$head(tags$style("body {background-color: #ADD8E6; }"))),
>
> tableOutput("dummy")   ) ))
> ```

server.R

> shinyServer(function(input, output) {   output$dummy <- renderTable({
>       data.frame(A=1:4,B=2:5,C=rep("aaa",4))   }) })

What I get is this

[image]

and what I would like to get (I used GIMP to recreate it) is

[image]

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A solution has been given on the [shiny google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/lBg8IP2qToo):

```
runApp(
  list(ui = bootstrapPage(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Rummy"),
    sidebarPanel( tags$hr() ),

    mainPanel(

      tableOutput("dummy"),
      # change style:    
      tags$head(tags$style("#dummy table {background-color: red; }", media="screen", type="text/css"))
    )

  )
  )

  ,
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$dummy <- renderTable({ data.frame(A=1:4,B=2:5,C=rep("aaa",4)) }) 
  }

  )
)
```

I also invite you to read this discussion on the shiny google group, which shows how to use the **pander** package to generate html tables and insert them in a shiny app. This allows a more flexible control of the style.

Comment: A nice approach, but it fills all the space to the right of the table in red too. Any solution that adapts to the width of the table?

Comment: @Rufo Good question. I have not been able to add a style to the table only with jQuery, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rufo I have modified my answer now.